# Usage of enclosing braces {} as arguments to commands and their options

Tags: bash, shell

#### Examples

I've recently found examples of using pairs of enclosing braces `{}`, with nothing in between the opening and closing braces, as arguments to commands and even to their options:

`cat foo | xargs -I{} echo {}`

`find . -size 0 -exec rm -i {} \;`

#### No Documentation

My problem is that I cannot find a documentation in the [GNU Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) that describes the usage of `{}` in such context as in the examples above.

I do not think it is a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), because a dollar sign must precede the enclosing braces in a parameter expansion as in `${}`.

It cannot be a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) either, because it takes the form of `{x..y[..incr]}`, where `x` and `y` are not optional.

It also cannot be a [command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) either, because `{}` is used as arguments.

#### Questions

1. What does a pair of enclosing braces `{}` even mean, in general, as an argument to any command that accepts it?
2. Where can I find a documentation that describes the usage of `{}` as arguments?

Comment: Some commands have this options `{}` - meaning `targets` to act on, with `find` command, it's remove/`rm` found files.

Answer (score 18):

These curly braces are left alone by bash; they belong to `find` and `xargs`, respectively, and are described in their man-pages.

## `man find`

> ### `-exec` *command* `;`
>
> Execute *command*; true if 0 status is returned.  All following arguments to find are
>                 taken to be arguments to the command until an argument consisting of `;` is encountered.  The string `{}` is replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it  is
>                 alone,  as  in some versions of `find`.  Both of these constructions might need to be
>                 escaped (with a `\`) or quoted to protect them from expansion by  the  shell.   See
>                 the  EXAMPLES  section  for examples of the use of the `-exec` option.  The specified
>                 *command* is run once for each matched file.  The command is executed in the starting
>                 directory.    There  are unavoidable security problems surrounding use of the `-exec`
>                 action; you should use the `-execdir` option instead.
>
> ### `-exec` *command* `{}` `+`
>
> This variant of the `-exec` action runs the specified *command* on the selected  files,
>                 but  the command line is built by appending each selected file name at the end; the
>                 total number of invocations of the command will be much less  than  the  number  of
>                 matched  files.   The  command line is built in much the same way that `xargs` builds
>                 its command lines.  Only one instance of `{}` is allowed within the  command.   The
>                 command  is  executed in the starting directory.  If `find` encounters an error, this
>                 can sometimes cause an immediate exit, so some pending commands may not be  run  at
>                 all.  This variant of `-exec` always returns true.
>
> ### `-execdir` *command* `;`
>
> ### `-execdir` *command* `{}` `+`
>
> Like  `-exec`,  but the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the
>                 matched file, which is not normally the directory in which you started find.   This
>                 a  much more secure method for invoking commands, as it avoids race conditions during resolution of the paths to the matched files.  As with the  `-exec`  action,  the
>                 `+`  form  of  `-execdir`  will build a command line to process more than one matched
>                 file, but any given invocation of command will only list files that  exist  in  the
>                 same  subdirectory.   If you use this option, you must ensure that your `$PATH` environment variable does not reference `.`; otherwise, an attacker can  run  any  commands  they like by leaving an appropriately-named file in a directory in which you
>                 will run `-execdir`.  The same applies to having entries in `$PATH` which are empty  or
>                 which  are  not  absolute  directory  names.  If `find` encounters an error, this can
>                 sometimes cause an immediate exit, so some pending commands may not be run at  all.
>                 The  result  of the action depends on whether the `+` or the `;` variant is being used;
>                 `-execdir` *command* `{}` `+` always returns true, while `-execdir` *command* `{}` `;` returns true
>                 only if *command* returns 0.

## `man xargs`

> ### `-I` *replace-str*
>
> Replace occurrences of *replace-str* in the initial-arguments with  names  read  from
>                 standard  input.   Also,  unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the
>                 separator is the newline character.  Implies `-x` and `-L` `1`.
>
> ### `-i`[*replace-str*], `--replace`[`=`*replace-str*]
>
> This option is a synonym for `-I`*replace-str* if *replace-str* is specified.  If the *replace-str* argument is missing, the effect is the same as `-I{}`.  This option is deprecated; use `-I` instead.

Edit: and here *WHY* bash ignores those curly braces:

## `man bash`

> ### `{` *list*`;` `}`
>
> *list*  is simply executed in the current shell environment.  *list* must be terminated with a newline or semicolon.  This is known as a group command.  The return status is the exit status  of
>                 list.   Note  that unlike the metacharacters *(* and *)*, *{* and *}* are reserved words and must occur
>                 where a reserved word is permitted to be recognized.  Since they do not  cause  a  word  break,
>                 they must be separated from list by whitespace or another shell metacharacter.

For emphasis: **list must be terminated with a newline or semicolon**.

Comment: Thank you! I'm annoyed that whoever wrote `man xargs` did not even bother to explain what `{}` actually means, nor did the author redirect (no pun intended) the reader to the explanation of `-exec` in the man-page of `find`.

Comment: @NikoGambt - I sympathise ...

Comment: @NikoGambt Well, {} doesn't really mean anything to xargs, except for being the default value for -i, which is deprecated. I'm not sure what explanation is necessary beyond that. In the example you posted, it might as well have been `xargs -Iab echo ab`; it's a purely arbitrary choice.

Comment: @Random832 After doing some more testing with `-I`, I now understand what that option actually does. Yes, `{}` is arbitrary, as you said.

I was just confused by the explanation `If the replace-str argument is missing, the effect is the same as -I{}`. If `-I` without argument were the same as `-I{}`, then `cat foo | xargs -I echo {}` would produce the same result as running `cat foo | xargs -I{} echo {}`. However, they are not the same. The former is an error, and what confused me even more was the error message `xargs: {}: No such file or directory`, but that's just due to implementation.

Comment: _list must be terminated by a newline_ and _`{` is a keyword, so must be delimited (with space, `<`, `>`, `(`...)_ But here, `{}` would more likely conflict with brace expansion. But again in `bash` and most other shells (the feature  itself comes from `csh`), while `{a,b}` (and `{a}` in some shells) is treated specially by the shell, `{}` is not. Note that in `bash` `{(uname)}` for instance also works, so it's not only `;` and newline (`&` is another obvious omission)

Comment: @NikoGambt `-I` (uppercase I) *cannot* be run without an argument. The argument to `-I` was `echo`. This is the primary difference between `-I` and `-i` (and the reason -i is deprecated, since options with non-required arguments are uncommon and confusing)

Comment: @Random832 Ah, makes sense! So, `cat foo | xargs -I echo {}` erred, because argument to `-I` is compulsory, which means `echo` is treated as the argument of `-I` and `{}` is treated as the command to be run! Thank you! The error message `xargs: {}: No such file or directory` is not that helpful, but now it makes sense because `xargs` tried to find the non-existent command `{}`.